# jQuery Append/CSS transition conflicts

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

Attempting to recreate a card stack click through gallery effect similar to: http://www.susannechmela.de/

I've got the JS adding the clicked cards to another UL and then, on reaching the last one, moving them back to the first list.

The CSS includes transitions to account for the "pop in" effect. It seems like the yellow card is getting both the "li + li" and "li + li + li" transition.

Is there something easy I'm missing? I've switched the order they're getting added and re-added. The cards need to stack in the reverse order of when they were taken away (rebuilding the original stack).

html:

```
<div>
<ul id="first">

<li><img></li>
<li><img></li>
<li><img></li>
</ul>
<ul id="first_hidden">

</ul>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOwzrO

Comment: Like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGQmvQ

Comment: Hmm... That one's dropping the cards in and out.

Comment: What exactly is supposed to happen on click? If your assumption about the problem is correct, you can use `:nth-child(2)` instead of `li+li` (and so on).

Comment: The core functionality is supposed to resemble this: http://www.susannechmela.de/

On click, the top card will disappear exposing the one beneath it until the last one. When the last one is clicked, the cards will "restack" in the opposite order with the first card being on top, second one behind, so on. 

The issue I'm having is getting the cards to appear in the correct order. The top card shows up first and then cascades down. I need the second card to appear first and then the top one on top of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a relatively positioned container and make absolutely positioned children elements within it. You should modify the children elements with JQuery to position and layer via z-index. **See demo below**

```js
// reset stack
function showAllCards(thisStack) {
  var allCards = thisStack.find('span');
  $(allCards.get().reverse()).each(function(i) {
    var time = i * 150;
    var card = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
      card.addClass('show');
    }, time);

  });
}


// set up cards in stack
$($(".stack span").get().reverse()).each(function(i) {
  console.log(i);
  var thisCard = $(this);
  var offset = 10 * i;
  thisCard.css({
    'right': offset + 'px',
    'top': offset + 'px',
    'z-index': i
  });
});


// click stack
$('.stack').click(function() {
  var thisStack = $(this);
  var nextCard = $(this).find('span.show').first();
  nextCard.toggleClass('show');
  if (nextCard.hasClass('last')) {
    showAllCards(thisStack);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
div.stack {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
div.stack:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
span {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background: #fff;
  font-family: monospace;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}
.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stack">
  <span class="show">First</span>
  <span class="show">Second</span>
  <span class="show">Third</span>
  <span class="last show">Fourth</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, that looks great.